# Error in getting address of a location in android

Tags: android, gps, location

based on this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/. I can now get latitude and longtitude based on location. Now I', trying to get the exact address with Geocoder: (Main is the class code above belongs to)

```
GPSTracker GPS = new GPSTracker(Main.this);

double latitude = GPS.getLatitude();
double longitude = GPS.getLongitude();

Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(Main.this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
```

LogCat says:

```
07-06 11:29:41.911: W/System.err(1670): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Comment: size of `addresses` is equal to 0, so you cant get first index

Comment: does this mean that geocoder fails to populate List from location, or wrong declaration of List?

Comment: I think first Idea is right, before getting address check size of list, if is bigger that 0 then get your data,

Comment: It's good to prevent error, but I'm still not getting the string of address since the size of list is still 0

Comment: check `getFromLocation` function with google API ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1 )

Comment: Please look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598609/gps-coordinates-using-location-manager-get-printed-as-null/24600264#24600264

Answer (score 0):

```
GPSTracker GPS = new GPSTracker(Main.this);

double latitude = GPS.getLatitude();
double longitude = GPS.getLongitude();

Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(Main.this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
if(addresses!=null && addresses.size()!=0){

    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

}
```

//if(addresses!=null && addresses.size()!=0)...check this portion..your address cannot be null and and the the size of array should not be zero...

Comment: if(addresses!=null && addresses.size()!=0)...check this portion..your address cannot be null and and the the size of array should not be zero...