# Geolocation in android

Tags: android, w3c-geolocation

My question may be irrelevant but I want to know can I use [this api](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)  in `android` .

Comment: There is an example. By android, you mean native android app or Phonegap app?

Comment: @PurpleDroid I mean native android app.

Comment: Do you just want to find your current location?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest yes .

Comment: @ShishupalShakya please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach using [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) api in android.

### Step 1: Use the Services connected method provided to check if Google Play Servcies are available.

```
private boolean servicesConnected() {
    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());

    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG,
                getString(R.string.play_services_available));

        // Continue
        return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
    } else {
        // Display an error dialog
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,
                getActivity(), 0);
        if (dialog != null) {
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
            errorFragment.show(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    LocationUtils.APPTAG);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

## Step2: Make Sure you've implemented the ShowError Dialog Method along with the ErrorDialog Fragment

```
private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {

    // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
    Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
            getActivity(),
            LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

    // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
    if (errorDialog != null) {

        // Create a new DialogFragment in which to show the error dialog
        ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();

        // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
        errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);

        // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
        errorFragment.show(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager(),
                LocationUtils.APPTAG);
    }
}

/**
 * Define a DialogFragment to display the error dialog generated in
 * showErrorDialog.
 */
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    // Global field to contain the error dialog
    private Dialog mDialog;

    /**
     * Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
     */
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public ErrorDialogFragment() {
        super();
        mDialog = null;
    }

    /**
     * Set the dialog to display
     * 
     * @param dialog
     *            An error dialog
     */
    public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
        mDialog = dialog;
    }

    /*
     * This method must return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
     */
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return mDialog;
    }
}
```

### Step 3: Find the Latitude & Longitude.

```
public void getAddress(View v) {
        // In Gingerbread and later, use Geocoder.isPresent() to see if a
        // geocoder is available.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD
                && !Geocoder.isPresent()) {
            // No geocoder is present. Issue an error message
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_geocoder_available,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (servicesConnected()) {
            // Get the current location
            Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
            Lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            Lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            LatLng = Double.toString(Lat) + "," + Double.toString(Lng);
            // Show the location in a toast message
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), LatLng, 0).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "servicesConnected() == false",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

If you need more information please refer to my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598609/gps-coordinates-using-location-manager-get-printed-as-null/24600264#24600264) page.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept. If this was useful :)

Comment: @ SeahawksRdaBest , currently I am doing same thing to fetch current location but I want to do same thing using geolocation api since it requires wifi and cell towers to fetch location status .

Comment: @ShishupalShakya in that case use Location Manager, specifically http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String).                                            The the getLastKnownLocation method will return a Location object. From this object you can then retrieve the Latitude and Longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this api in android but you can use this api in phonegap technology which is cross platform Hybrid application where we can develop

Comment: Is there any way to use over android .

Comment: instead you go for locationManager in android....

Comment: you can follow this tutorial to have maps in android http://codebybrian.com/2012/12/06/google_maps_android_v2_sample.html,http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/